# Zen Coding interval on producing N elements

Tags: emmet

here's a quick question on Zen Coding. If:

```
div.foo-$*3
```

produces this:

```
<div class="foo-1"></div>
<div class="foo-2"></div>
<div class="foo-3"></div>
```

What if I wanted to generate, for example, `.foo-27` until `.foo-245`? Is there a way to set an interval in generating elements in such a manner? Is it possible for the current version of Zen Coding? I know manually deleting unnecessary tags is a way, but Zen Coding is supposed to quicken stuff up, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it’s not possible. Since it’s very specific use case, you may fill-up issue at https://github.com/sergeche/zen-coding/issues

If it get enough votes, I may think about upgrading syntax for this feature.